# relative path for database file in config file

Tags: sql-server-ce, config

I've created a WCF REST service that uses nhibernate to connect to sql server compact edition database. Hence I configure the NHibernate datasource like:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=[Path]\MyDb.sdf</property>
```

The annoyance I'm running into now is that I can't figure out how to avoid having to write out the absolute path in the config. This is annoying since I keep the database file as part of the project in the App_Data folder. So I shouldn't have to update the path e.g. when I deploy the project to another location, even if the absolute path is different.

Using procmon I noticed that if I don't write an absolute pat in the Data Source config, it is interpreted as relative to the path: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0**.

Is it possible have nhibernate assume we want to relate the path to the application bin folder instead (which is where my App_Data/MyDb.sdf ends up)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sdf
```

`|DataDirectory|` points to the `App_Data` folder.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone else you can use this to generate other relatives, ie: `|DataDirectory|\..\bin\File.sdf`.  If only I could vote this up more, thanks, perfect.  Do you know of any other path keywords the connection string supports or is it just that one?

Comment: Worth noting that Paul's tip above does work, despite what has been said on other SO posts.

Comment: Yea, a link to the reference where the keyword definitions are buried would be great... (cite you work)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you have your NHibernate configuration in a XML file instead of building the configuration programmatically using the NHibernate configuration interface?

If you have the flexibility, this is how I'd do it:

```
var path = // dynamically generate your path
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, String.Format("Data Source={0};", path));
... // other configuration properties
```

All of the classes you need are under the NHibernate.Cfg namespace. There's also Fluent NHibernate, which provides a much cleaner interface for building your configuration.

Hope that helps!