# SQL CE Not updating database values from windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am building a inventory based application that can be directly run from any pc without any installation and so i am using SQL CE.. On Start, I am checking if database is present. If Not i am creating new database as :

```
        try
        {
            string conString = "Data Source='ITM.sdf';LCID=1033;Password=ABCDEF; Encrypt = TRUE;";
            SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(conString);
            engine.CreateDatabase();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Database Already Present");
        }
```

The database is created properly and i can access the database to create tables as well.. The Problem i am facing is - I am inserting and updating records in windows form on button click with code :

```
         using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(DatabaseConnection.connectionstring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            String Name = NameTxt.Text.ToString();
            String Phone = PhoneTxt.Text.ToString();
            double balance = Double.Parse(BalanceTxt.Text.ToString());
            String City = CityTxt.Text.ToString();
            string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Customers (Name,Phone,Balance,City)" + "Values(@name,@phone, @bal, @city)";
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sqlquery, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bal", balance);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", City);
            int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (x > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Occured. Cannot Insert the data");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

and Updation Code is

```
        using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(DatabaseConnection.connectionstring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            int idtoedit = select_id_edit;
            String Name = NameEditTxt.Text.ToString();
            String Phone = metroTextBox1.Text.ToString();
            String City = CityEditTxt.Text.ToString();
            string sqlquery = "Update Customers Set Name = @name, Phone = @phone,City = @city where Id = @id";
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sqlquery, connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idtoedit);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", City);
            int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (x > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Occured. Cannot Insert the data");
            }
            loadIntoGrid();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Whenever i execute code for inserting and updating records - Records are reflected in datagrid filled with adapter from database table. But once i restart the application, values do not appear in database. Once in a million, values are reflected in database. I cannot understand the reason behind this issue.

I have reffered to these articles :

[C# - ExecuteNonQuery() isn't working with SQL Server CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193017/c-sharp-executenonquery-isnt-working-with-sql-server-ce)

[Insert, Update, Delete are not applied on SQL Server CE database file for Windows Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113464/insert-update-delete-are-not-applied-on-sql-server-ce-database-file-for-window)

But since i am creating database programmatically - It is getting created directly to bin/debug directory and i cannot see it in solution explorer in visual studio for changing copy options

Comment: Just to clarify are both update and insert query running **at the same time** when `if (x > 0)`?

Comment: No.. They are running separately

Answer (score 1):

You probably rewrite your database file with a blank copy from your project.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310597/2224701). You should not store your database in a bin folder, rather you should find a place in user's or public profile in AppData or another folder, depending on your needs.

The connection string would look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ITMContext" connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\ITM.sdf';LCID=1033;Password=ABCDEF; Encrypt = TRUE;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0">
```

You shuld deploy your db file with your custom code run at app's starup to a chosen location, see this ErikEJ blog: http://erikej.blogspot.cz/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html

```
private const string dbFileName = "Chinook.sdf";

private static void CreateIfNotExists(string fileName)
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    // Set the data directory to the users %AppData% folder            
    // So the database file will be placed in:  C:\\Users\\<Username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\            
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);

    // Enure that the database file is present
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName)))
    {
        //Get path to our .exe, which also has a copy of the database file
        var exePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
            new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);
        //Copy the file from the .exe location to the %AppData% folder
        System.IO.File.Copy(
            System.IO.Path.Combine(exePath, fileName),
            System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName));
    }
}
```

Check also [this post](http://erikej.blogspot.cz/2010/05/faq-why-does-my-changes-not-get-saved.html).

> You have several options to change this behavior. If your sdf file is
>   part of the content of your project, this will affect how data is
>   persisted. Remember that when you debug, all output of your project
>   (including the sdf) if in the bin/debug folder.
>
> - You can decide not to include the sdf file as part of your project and manage the file location runtime.
> - If you are using "copy if newer", and project changes you make to the database will overwrite any runtime/debug changes.
> - If you are using "Do not copy", you will have to specify the location in code (as two levels above where your program is running).
> - If you have "Copy always", any changes made during runtime will always be overwritten

The database file in your project can be different when debugging or not. Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053292/2224701). You might be writting your records to another copy of the database file.

Comment: Still Not working.. as per your suggestion. i checked on start of application if database is present in appdata folder. if yes - then i carried on insert and update statement. If not - i first created database in bin folder and then moved to appdata folder. My connection string for update and insert statements is :  public static string connectionstring = "Data Source='|DataDirectory|/ITM.sdf';LCID=1033;Password=ABCDEF; Encrypt = TRUE;";
 Still the same issue. Changes reflect on runtime,but do not reflect after the app is restarted

Comment: And when the app is running, the updated/inserted data are there?

Comment: Yes. While the app is running. all the values are updated/inserted. once i restart the app. the values are gone

Comment: Perhaps watching the db file size while launching/debugging your app could help you identify where in your code gets the db file rewritten/modified or whatever. From the code posted I do not see a problem.

Comment: I tried testing. I Found two behaviours.  1. The Database FIle Size is not getting changed even after adding 40 new records. 2. After adding 40 records i closed the app, those 40 records were present even after restarting. Again i tried Inserting 1 new record. The PRoblem occured and that one record is not present after restart of app

Comment: Try to comment out (disable) your db creation code and see if it helps. Also make sure that your connection string allways points to a db file in AppData folder.

Comment: I Understood your point of making - Copy if Newer for Database. But please can u help me with this changes to be done, if i am pulling the database from appdata folder. This Database file is not visible in solution explorer. how to change copy options for such database file

Comment: Tried COmmenting the code for database creation and checked. The issue is still there. sometimes the changes are saved, sometimes not

Comment: There is no problem with your insert/update code, it works. The problem is, that something is preventing the changes from being commited, either SQL CE transaction does not commit because you have the file opened elsewhere or some part of your code that I do not see, causes the problem. Try to use explicit transactions or use ProcessExplorer to see, what other process has the handle to your .sdf file opened. Or create a small console app with just insert/update and see, if this works allways.